# SQL - Declare scalar variable error (for SSRS Report)

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, variables, reporting-services, syntax

This is the error I am getting when I run the query shown below:  Must declare the scalar variable "@ReportDate". Incorrect syntax near 'Label'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GroupOrder'. Must declare the scalar variable "@Demographics1".

How do I write this query to run error-free?

My ReportDate is Datetime
My Demographics1 is varchar(max)

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   'Age' DemographicGroup, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, [Date of Birth],  @ReportDate) < 25 THEN '<=25' 
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, [Date of Birth], @ReportDate) BETWEEN 25 AND 35 THEN '26-35' 
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, [Date of Birth], @ReportDate) BETWEEN 36 AND 45 THEN '36-45' 
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, [Date of Birth], @ReportDate) > 45 THEN '46+' 
                            END Label, 
                           CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, [Date of Birth], @ReportDate) < 25 THEN 1 
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, [Date of Birth], @ReportDate) BETWEEN 25 AND 35 THEN 2 
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, [Date of Birth], @ReportDate) BETWEEN 36 AND 45 THEN 3 
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, [Date of Birth], @ReportDate) > 45 THEN 4 
                            END GroupOrder
INTO        #Demo2
FROM     [dbo].[Dim_Borrower]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'Marital Status', [Marital Status], 1
FROM     [dbo].[Dim_Borrower]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'Race', Race, 1
FROM     [dbo].[Dim_Borrower]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'Sex', Sex, 1
FROM     [dbo].[Dim_Borrower]

                      SELECT   *,DemographicGroup + ' - ' + Label RealLabel
                      FROM     #Demo2
                      WHERE  DemographicGroup IN (@Demographics1)
                      ORDER BY DemographicGroup, GroupOrder
```

Comment: Which dbms? (This is not ANSI SQL syntax for sure...)

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole query?As it is you have 2 queries

Comment: Missed to declare variables `Declare @ReportDate date,@Demographics1 varchar(50)` other than this there is no error in query

Answer (score 1):

At which point you have declared these 2 variables @ReportDate and @Demographics1.

you must have some line like

```
Declare @ReportDate DateTime;
Delcare @Demographics1 varchar(max);
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Where in the query do I place the "declaration"s? I understand that I have to do it... I just want too know where

Comment: At the very beginning of query, you also need to assign some value to it. Using 'Set' statement

Comment: How about this (Right after Select Distinct)DECLARE  atReportDate Datetime = '6/27/2013'
DECLARE atDemographics1 varchar(max)

 SET atReportDate = '6/27/2013'
  atDemographics1 =  'Marital Status'